# keep leading zeros when I add quotation mark in excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, quotation-marks, leading-zero

I have a list of SSN in my excel file (9 digits, some of which have leading zeros, no hyphen).

I keep them in the special format (numero da seguranca social  in portugues) so I can keep leading zeros in the column.

I want to add ' ', to the column so that I can search them in SQL query in bulk.

When I use concatenating formula ( concatenating("'",B2,"'",",")), the leading zeros are gone.

How can I achieve the result of 00XXXXXX   as '00XXXXXX',  ?

Thank you!

Comment: Ensure that `B2` is stored as a text. Change the format from general to text, it should work

Comment: When I changed the format from special to text, I lose the leading zeros in B2. Any reason why did that happen?

Comment: `="'"&TEXT(B2,"000000000")&"'"`

Comment: @tigeravatar  Thank you!  That worked well,  really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your special format is, but I am guessing that if the value is `xx` the format makes it look like `00xx`. Similar to a zip code.

So the value when you change it to text looks like `xx`.

I can think of 2 ways to fix it

1. Write a formulae which basically does what the special format does. For example it would make `xx` as `00xx`. Then you can concatenate this new value like u mentioned earlier
2. Copy the values from excel to notepad and then paste it to excel again. When you copy from excel to notepad, the formatted value, i.e. `00xx` will get copied to notepad which can then be pasted to excel in a separate unformatted cell.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to copy your SSN column from your file and paste it into a new file all by itself.  Then, while ensuring that the SSN numbers are formatted with any appropriate leading zeros, save the new file as a text/tab delimited file and close it.  Now, using Excel's Open File command, select your text file and on Step 3 of 3, select Text for the Column data format.  Now, you should be able to select that column of data and copy it back to your main file and perform your concatena

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ''00XXXXXX' or "'00XXXXXX"? That is, add one single quote before the number and Excel interprets it as a string, not a number. If you will not do any numeric operations with it, then it should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input.

I ended up using @tigeravatar 's method, which is

**="'"&TEXT(B2,"000000000")&"'"&","**

and it worked for me.

Thank you!